# Row Number Based on Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @delimiter nvarchar(2) = char(10);
declare @objectName sysname = 'dbo.table_1';
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with CTE as (

  select 
    0  as line_number
  , @objectName as [object_name]
  , ltrim(rtrim(object_definition( object_id(@objectName)))) as def
  , convert(nvarchar(max), N'') as line

  union all

  select 
    line_number + 1 
  , @objectName as [object_name]
  , substring(def, charindex(@delimiter, def) + len(@delimiter), len(def) - (charindex(@delimiter, def)))
  , left(def, charindex(@delimiter, def)) as line
  from 
    CTE
  where 
    charindex(@delimiter, def) <> 0

 )
select 
    --a.line_number
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[object_name] order by a.[line_number]) as [new_line_num]
    ,a.[object_name]
    -----
    ,a.line
    -----
    ,case
        when a.line like '%openquery%' then 'OPENQUERY'
        else ''
        end as [open_query_label]

    -----
    ,case
        when a.line like '%openquery%' then ROW_NUMBER () OVER(partition by a.[object_name] Order by (select 1) )
        else 0 
        end as [open_query_group]
from 
    CTE as a
where 
    a.line_number >= 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

This query produces the following output:

```
new_line_num    object_name   line            open_query_label  open_query_group
147             dbo.table_1   ,max(case when quest...)          0
148             dbo.table_1   ,max(case when quest...)          0
149             dbo.table_1   ,max(case when quest...)          0
150             dbo.table_1   ,max(case when quest...)          0
```

My ultimate goal is to grab all of `OPENQUERY` parts of each definition.

The way I'm going to do this is by labeling the line where the `OPENQUERY` starts and then grabbing the next 15 lines. It won't be 100% accurate, but it will be pretty close.

I want the output to look like this:

```
new_line_num     object_name     line                 open_query_label          open_query_group
142              dbo.table_name  ,max(case when...                              0
153              dbo.table_name  OPENQUERY([whatever    OPENQUERY               1    
154              dbo.table_name  'select                                        2
```

After `open_query_group` takes a value of 15, I'd like it to go back to 0 unless there is another `OPENQUERY` in the SQL statement. When that happens, I'd like the `OPEN_QUERY_GROUP` number to start back at 1.

Any suggestions on how to manipulate the ROW_NUMBER function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial solution, I cant use your CTE to do anything, so I made some dummy data.

```
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1, ''), (2, ''), (3, 'OPENQUERY'), (4, ''), (5, ''), (6, ''), (7, ''), (8, ''), (9, ''), (10, ''), (11, 'OPENQUERY')
    , (12, ''), (13, ''), (14, ''), (15, ''), (16, ''), (17, ''), (18, ''), (19, ''), (20, ''), (21, ''), (22, '')
    , (23, ''), (24, ''), (25, ''), (26, ''), (27, ''), (28, ''), (29, ''), (30, ''), (31, ''), (32, ''), (33, '')
    , (34, ''), (35, ''), (36, 'OPENQUERY'), (37, ''), (38, ''), (39, ''), (40, ''), (41, ''), (41, '')) a (new_line_num, open_query_label))
```

The trick is to first create one group for each instance of OPENQUERY.

I do this by toing an aggregate sum, setting the row value to1 where there is an OPENQUERY and to 0 else. This makes a distinct set of groups, 1 pr OPENQUERY (plus anything that comes before the first openquery)

```
SELECT
        new_line_num
       ,open_query_label
       ,SUM(IIF(open_query_label = 'OPENQUERY', 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY new_line_num) grp
    FROM cte
```

This gives us this (partial result)

```
+--------------+------------------+-----+
| new_line_num | open_query_label | grp |
+--------------+------------------+-----+
|            1 |                  |   0 |
|            2 |                  |   0 |
|            3 | OPENQUERY        |   1 |
|            4 |                  |   1 |
|            5 |                  |   1 |
|            6 |                  |   1 |
|            7 |                  |   1 |
|            8 |                  |   1 |
|            9 |                  |   1 |
|           10 |                  |   1 |
|           11 | OPENQUERY        |   2 |
|           12 |                  |   2 |
|           13 |                  |   2 |
|           14 |                  |   2 |
+--------------+------------------+-----+
```

Now i pack this as CTE2, and then I just use row_number to get the groups:

```
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1, ''), (2, ''), (3, 'OPENQUERY'), (4, ''), (5, ''), (6, ''), (7, ''), (8, ''), (9, ''), (10, ''), (11, 'OPENQUERY')
    , (12, ''), (13, ''), (14, ''), (15, ''), (16, ''), (17, ''), (18, ''), (19, ''), (20, ''), (21, ''), (22, '')
    , (23, ''), (24, ''), (25, ''), (26, ''), (27, ''), (28, ''), (29, ''), (30, ''), (31, ''), (32, ''), (33, '')
    , (34, ''), (35, ''), (36, 'OPENQUERY'), (37, ''), (38, ''), (39, ''), (40, ''), (41, ''), (41, '')) a (new_line_num, open_query_label)),
cte2
AS
(SELECT
        new_line_num
       ,open_query_label
       ,SUM(IIF(open_query_label = 'OPENQUERY', 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY new_line_num) grp
    FROM cte)
SELECT
    new_line_num
   ,open_query_label
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY new_line_num) open_query_group
FROM cte2
```

Partial Result:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| new_line_num | open_query_label | open_query_group |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|            1 |                  |                1 |
|            2 |                  |                2 |
|            3 | OPENQUERY        |                1 |
|            4 |                  |                2 |
|            5 |                  |                3 |
|            6 |                  |                4 |
|            7 |                  |                5 |
|            8 |                  |                6 |
|            9 |                  |                7 |
|           10 |                  |                8 |
|           11 | OPENQUERY        |                1 |
|           12 |                  |                2 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Finally we want the first to rows to start at 0 in stead of 1, and for the open_query_group to roll around from 15 to 0

```
SELECT
    new_line_num
   ,open_query_label
   ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY new_line_num) 
    - iif(grp=0,1,0))%16
   open_query_group
FROM cte2
```

This treats the first grp (0) specially, and uses modulus 16 to make the row number roll over from 15 to 0.

The final result:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| new_line_num | open_query_label | open_query_group |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|            1 |                  |                0 |
|            2 |                  |                1 |
|            3 | OPENQUERY        |                1 |
|            4 |                  |                2 |
|            5 |                  |                3 |
|            6 |                  |                4 |
|            7 |                  |                5 |
|            8 |                  |                6 |
|            9 |                  |                7 |
|           10 |                  |                8 |
|           11 | OPENQUERY        |                1 |
|           12 |                  |                2 |
|           13 |                  |                3 |
|           14 |                  |                4 |
|           15 |                  |                5 |
|           16 |                  |                6 |
|           17 |                  |                7 |
|           18 |                  |                8 |
|           19 |                  |                9 |
|           20 |                  |               10 |
|           21 |                  |               11 |
|           22 |                  |               12 |
|           23 |                  |               13 |
|           24 |                  |               14 |
|           25 |                  |               15 |
|           26 |                  |                0 |
|           27 |                  |                1 |
|           28 |                  |                2 |
|           29 |                  |                3 |
|           30 |                  |                4 |
|           31 |                  |                5 |
|           32 |                  |                6 |
|           33 |                  |                7 |
|           34 |                  |                8 |
|           35 |                  |                9 |
|           36 | OPENQUERY        |                1 |
|           37 |                  |                2 |
|           38 |                  |                3 |
|           39 |                  |                4 |
|           40 |                  |                5 |
|           41 |                  |                6 |
|           41 |                  |                7 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```